# return value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and I am little bit confused about the syntax.

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My question is If I write onsubmit="return validateForm()" or write onsubmit="validateForm()". What's the difference between these two syntax. So I submitted before just an example.

Here it is example

Event = function(); or Event = return function();

What's the difference between these two syntax

Comment: The difference is that the latter makes no sense and/or is invalid. Do you have any more context for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onsubmit="validateForm()"` just calls the function and whatever is returned is lost and does not effect anything.
But in `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` the returned value is returned again and if false will not submit the form and if true will continue the submitting process.
So you can use it like:

```
function check()
{
    if(document.getElementByName("fname").value == ""){
        return(false);  //Do not submit the form
    }
    return(true);  //Submit the forum
}

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return(check());" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

They're both invalid.

The `return` statement should be used *within* a function. The expression following a `return` statement is what will be returned from the function, so:

```
function foo() {
    return 1234;
}

foo(); // => 1234
```

If you want to assign a function to the `Event` identifier, then you would do it like so:

```
Event = function() {
    // function body (what do you want the function to do?)
};
```

Comment: This is not the exact code. I just ask the difference between these syntax. It is just pseudo code

Comment: See my answer for why (posted in a few seconds) I think this is wrong

Comment: The OP added a whole bunch of code to the question (a late edit)... rendering my answer seemingly inappropriate.